# How to Render styles like font color and size which is present inside a span tag in xslt using xsl-fo?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am generating pdf files based on the output from a rich text editor, some of the components like font color, font size for a specific word or a paragraph comes like

```
 <p>Hello Hi <strong>skansdjnsjc</strong>
 <span style="color:#ce181e"><em>cddsklncjkdsv</em></span>
 <span style="color:#ce181e">sdsadsad</span></p>
```

And in my xslt file I did a template match like

```
  <xsl:template match="span">     
    <xsl:variable name="color">
     <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="@color">
         <xsl:value-of select="@color"/>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:text>black</xsl:text>
       </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:variable>
 </xsl:template>
```

But the required styles are not being rendered in the pdf file. Am I missing anything? or is there any solution to it.

Thanks For the help in advance !!!

Comment: In this case, `color` is not an attribute, but is just a substring within the `style` attribute. Extracting the color value from this style attribute is tricky, but depends on what version of XSLT you are using. Can you use XSLT 2.0 or above? Thanks!

Comment: I'm Using xslt 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, you could extract the color from the style attribute like so

```
<xsl:variable name="extractColor" select="tokenize(tokenize(@style, ';')[normalize-space(substring-before(., ':')) = 'color'], ':')[2]" />
```

Then, to set your `color` variable (setting it to `black` if no color was extracted), do this....

```
<xsl:variable name="color" select="($extractColor, 'black')[1]" />
```

Of course, if you extended to extract other values, you could create a function.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:my="my">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="span">
    <span>
        <xsl:variable name="color" select="(my:extract(@style, 'color'), 'black')[1]" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$color" />
    </span>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="my:extract">
      <xsl:param name="text" />
      <xsl:param name="name" />
      <xsl:sequence select="tokenize(tokenize($text, ';')[normalize-space(substring-before(., ':')) = $name], ':')[2]" />
  </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim , I'm able to write the values in the pdf , but the color code is printed instead of rendering in to that color

Comment: It sounds like you have two problems. One about extracting the color from the html, and another about using it in xsl-fo. As this particular question did not show any xsl-fo code at all, I can't really help about that. You may want to ask another question instead, showing the xsl-fo code you are using, and how you are trying to apply the color. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Tim , setting the extracted color value into <fo:inline > block does the job done !!! Thanks a lot for the solution